# Column not found in where with inner joins

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I have this mysql query:

```
select `sc_documentos`.*, `sc_clientesproveedores`.`nombre` as `cliente`,
`sc_documentos`.`descripcion` as `desc`, SUM(sc_documentos.total) AS sumaTotal,
`sc_series`.`nombre` as `serie`
from `sc_documentos`
inner join `sc_clientesproveedores` on `sc_clientesproveedores`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idCliente`
inner join `sc_series` on `sc_series`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idSerie`
where (`sumaTotal` >= 100 and `sumaTotal` <= 200 and `tipo` like '%presupuesto%'
and `sc_documentos`.`idUsuario` = 1682)
and `sc_documentos`.`deleted_at` is null order by `sc_documentos`.`created_at` desc
```

Mysql says: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sumaTotal' in 'where clause'

Please help I think that I can use more than one select o some, but don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query `sumaTotal` is an alias of `SUM(sd_documentos.total)`. So either use `HAVING sumaTotal >= 100 and sumaTotal <= 200` or `WHERE SUM(sc_documentos.total) >= 100 AND SUM(sc_documentos.total) <= 200`

Answer (score 0):

sumaTotal is an alias of SUM part in your query so you can change the query like that:

```
select `sc_documentos`.*, `sc_clientesproveedores`.`nombre` as `cliente`,
`sc_documentos`.`descripcion` as `desc`,
`sc_series`.`nombre` as `serie`
from `sc_documentos`
inner join `sc_clientesproveedores` on `sc_clientesproveedores`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idCliente`
inner join `sc_series` on `sc_series`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idSerie`
HAVING  (SUM(sc_documentos.total) >= 100 and SUM(sc_documentos.total) <= 200 and `tipo` like '%presupuesto%'
and `sc_documentos`.`idUsuario` = 1682)
and `sc_documentos`.`deleted_at` is null order by `sc_documentos`.`created_at` desc
```

Comment: try this but no results, anyway thanks so much for your effort and time!!

Answer (score 0):

This runs after simialbi instructions: (thanks again)

```
select `sc_documentos`.*, `sc_clientesproveedores`.`nombre` as `cliente`,
`sc_documentos`.`descripcion` as `desc`, SUM(sc_documentos.total) AS sumaTotal, 
`sc_series`.`nombre` as `serie` from `sc_documentos`
inner join `sc_clientesproveedores` on `sc_clientesproveedores`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idCliente`
inner join `sc_series` on `sc_series`.`id` = `sc_documentos`.`idSerie`
where (`tipo` like '%presupuesto%' and `sc_documentos`.`idUsuario` = 1682) and `sc_documentos`.`deleted_at` is null
group by `idCliente` having sumaTotal>=600 and sumaTotal<=800
order by `sc_documentos`.`created_at` desc
```